# Pass data from the Activity to SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

I'm not sure where the problem is. I thought if the activity would pass information to the surfaceview it implements. Basically I'm trying to make it so that when someone selects their choice of game layout from the main menu (passes it with Intent) it then goes to the PlayGame class. (I have it take the number given from the intent). That activity uses SurfaceView through a layout. Then down  in the surface view where it calls the images and assigns them I tried using an if else to determine which pictures it should be using. Didn't work. Not exactly sure what to do about it. If there is a better way to make it use the images from a previous selection on the main page. Looks like this.

Main Class (Just one of the buttons passing in intent)

```
Button surfButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play1_btn);
    surfButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View surfing)
        {
            Intent play = new Intent(Main.this, PlayGame.class);
            play.putExtra("gameType" , 1);
            startActivity(play);
        }
    });
```

PlayGame Class

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    Intent typ = getIntent();
    type = typ.getIntExtra("gameType", 0);

    setContentView(R.layout.game);        
    gameLoopView = (GameLoopView) findViewById(R.id.gnarlyned); 


}
```

Game Class:

```
private void loadImages(Context context) {
            type = playGame.type;
    Resources res = context.getResources();

    if (type == 1){
        skyImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.sky);

    }
    else if (type == 2){
        skyImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.snowbg);

    }
```

More images than just one, but to save space it's just the one. Any help would be appreciated. I'm sure I must have done something wrong there.

EDIT: Here is the log cat from the force close caused from this setup.

06-06 17:55:01.655: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16229): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-06 17:55:01.655: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16229): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fallacystudios.gnarlyned/fallacystudios.gnarlyned.PlayGame}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fallacystudios.gnarlyned.GameLoopView
06-06 17:55:01.655: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16229):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
06-06 17:55:01.655: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16229): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fallacystudios.gnarlyned.GameLoopView
06-06 17:55:01.655: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16229): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-06 17:55:01.655: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16229): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Then a whole bunch of heap size overflow

All this only happens when I have the if(gameType == 1) and else if(gameType == 2) in the loadImages section. Doing this to make it so only certain images are used when that map is selected. Not sure why that doesnt work.

Comment: What actually isn't working? I don't think I understand what the exact problem is.

Comment: Exactly when is the loadImage(Context context) method getting called? The Game class constructor? From the PlayGame gameLoopView object? What type is playGame.type, an int or an Integer?

Comment: @Joe loadImage is getting called in public Game (Context context) within the surfaceview. The surfaceview is called from the onCreate in PlayGame. playGame type is an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `loadImages` is being called from the Game constructor, then the problem is that when you inflate the view, you haven't yet defined playGame.type. Try extracting the intent extra before calling `setContentView`.

Comment: @TedHopp Dang I thought that would work, but it is still giving me problems. Not exactly sure what it is. Thanks though.

Comment: Odd. You've verified that the type being retrieved from the intent in PlayGame.onCreate is definitely what was passed from the Main? And if it is, that it is definitely _not_ being seen in Game? (I usually use an illegal value as the default for getIntExtra, that way I know whether it's being called correctly.)

Comment: @TedHopp Ya it is the same as what is being passed in main. And it is being extracted prior to the setcontentview. It's just when I try to get it in the surfaceview it wont get it. It force closes (I'll post the logcat above)

Comment: The force close is caused by a NullPointerException in Game.loadImages at line 524. I don't know exactly which line that is, but looking at your code, it seems to me the most likely problem is that playGame hasn't been initialized when loadImages is called.

Comment: @TedHopp It's weird. I've tried creating a variable in Game and I've tried both setting it equal to zero and setting it equal to playGame.type prior to loadImages being called. Stil gives me a nullpointer exception. Btw how do I get it to display the numbers for lines. I'll look at what is at that line.

Comment: Scratch that I found how to toggle the numbers on. Here is where it is saying it is occuring. This is in loadImages

Comment: 'if(type == 1){
   skyImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.sky);
   groundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ocean);
   dividerImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ocean);
   
   obstacle1Image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.shark);
   drinkImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.drink);
   obstacle2Image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.log);
   obstacle3Image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.bird);
   nedJumpImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.nedjump);
  }'

Comment: Type there was my attempt at using a variable in place of playGame.type. It is set equal to it just above. And the variable was initilized to zero at the start.

Comment: I can't follow what's going on any more. Could you edit your post to show the current code for PlayGame.onCreate, Game.loadImages, and the exact line that is generating the NPE?

Comment: @TedHopp Ok it's changed. Up above I also tried having that type=playGame.type in the games first context method and it didnt work there either. Oh and the line that it is saying doesnt work is in the last code post where the if is.

Comment: You mean to say that this line: `if (type == 1){` generates a NullPointerException? I don't think that's possible. How about surrounding your call to `loadImages` with a try/catch block; catch the NPE; print a stack trace; show a Toast that things didn't work; and call `finish()`.

Comment: Thats the line number it gave me. I'll go ahead and give that a try. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @TedHopp Ok so tried that. It didnt even make it to that part from what I can tell. I got a large variety of exceptions.

Comment: @TedHopp Ok after eliminating things I found that the actual NullPointer is not the if. It is the type = playGame.type. I've now tried it in the loadImages(), the Game(), and in the public class. The logcat error is following it. Not exactly sure why it is getting a nullpointer though. Shouldnt it be getting the information from the PlayGame class just fine?

Comment: How are you initializing `playGame`?

Comment: @TedHopp PlayGame the class or playGame.type? The class is an activity. If you mean how its initialized on the SurfaceView game it's PlayGame playGame; . If you mean type it's set to zero on PlayGame class and before the setContentView it's opens and gets the intent type.

Answer (score 0):

I've kind of done what you're attempting.  My solution was to set all the views in inner classes and then do your layout dynamically.  That way every widget/view can see what the other is doing.

Answer (score 0):

set `type` to `public static` in `PlayGame` Class and call intent extra before calling `setContentView` as Ted Hopp mentioned.